# How to put 2 divs next to one huge div

Tags: javascript, html, css

So there are a lot of questions like this on StackOverflow but there doesn't seem to be one that will be helpful in my case.

[image]

As you can see, I have 2 divs on the screen. One on the left which is

```
float:left;
```

and the one in the middle is

```
margin-left-auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

So my question is, when I want to put another div JUST like the one on the right on the left of the middle DIV, how will I go on to doing this?

```
float:right;
```

has been tried on the right div but that just puts it in a different line because of the left div being floated.

So how do I do this? Answers are greatly appreciated.

I can provide more code such as how the DIV"s are arranged if needed.

Comment: Set `float: left` to the middle div and last div as well. Use flexbox or `inline-block` instead, easy! :)

Comment: your syntax on margin-left should match margin-right.

Comment: When using float, you should be careful with `div`'s width. If the width over the screen width, it will add to the next line.

Comment: So I added float left to each of the three divs but then how would I center the middle div in the middle?

Comment: why float the left div? why not just give them percentage widths at this point, then margin: 0 auto;? why not use flexbox?

Comment: i'm asking cause i wonder why you need to float the div left to beign with

Answer (score 0):

**Flexbox solution**

1. Wrap the items inside a parent container and set the `display: flex`
2. `flex: 1` on the left and right items will grow and shrink it 1x.
3. `flex: 2` on the middle items will grow and shrink it 2x.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.left,
.right {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E77F24;

}
.middle {
  flex: 2;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="middle">2</div>
  <div class="right">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All I did was type

```
display: flex;
```

in the container div and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

To create a main body of content with a left and right sidebar, you can float:left and simply define a width for each div in the CSS.

```
ie: 
.div1 {width:25%}
.div2 {width:50%}
.div3 {width:25%}
```

If you want to account for padding, just reduce the amount divided by three on each div width.

```
ie: http://jsfiddle.net/simsketch/9tj4va6r/
```

It might help you to start out using a framework like Foundation or Bootstrap.
Foundation provides lots of starter templates to help get you started here.
http://foundation.zurb.com/templates.html

When using a grid system, instead of needing to define widths in your custom css, you can simply include the foundation.css library, and reference the classes.

```
ie: <div class="large-6">content</div>
```

For the layout you're after, this would do the trick.
http://foundation.zurb.com/templates/feed.html

What they're doing there is simply:

```
<div class="large-3"></div>
<div class="large-6"></div>
<div class="large-3"></div>
```

As long as the numbers add up to twelve, they will fit perfectly.

This has been a brief introduction to grid systems. Consult the following for more information:

```
http://foundation.zurb.com/
http://getbootstrap.com/
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp
```

These are the two most popular front-end frameworks but there are dozens more and they are all wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .div1{
    width:25%;
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    
   }
   .div2{
    width:50%;
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
   }
   .div3{
    width:25%;
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
    background-color:green;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
   }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="div1">First Div</div>
  <div class="div2">Second Div</div>
  <div class="div3">Third Div</div>
    </body>
```